# JTable data not stable when vertically scrolled

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, vertical-scrolling

I have developed a Java Swing application which consists of JTable. The JTable displays data of text file. The textfile is comma separated. After displaying i am summing up the totals and displaying them in another JTable which can be vertically scrolled. But when the rows in the table are more, then the JTable is not stable when vertically scrolled. The data gets repeated or the file gets corrupted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is maybe (no code, no hash) some issues with

1) [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html),

2) why `JTable` loads data on Runtime or there un-know concurency between `JTables` and one `TableModel`

3) add your data to the [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

4) better would be implements `DefaultTableModel` for each of `JTable` separately

more [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)

Comment: I also suspected an NPE somewhere during execution ;), but it's difficult to say that without code... :(

Comment: +1 good summary. Violating the [opaque property](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) is also a candidate.